# converting Spring Cloud Stream code to functional based for Spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

I have to update code sending RabbitMQ using Spring Cloud Stream from spring boot 2 to spring boot 3 using functional based beans

Can somebody help convert this simplified version?

```
@EnableBinding(MySink.class)
public class RabbitMQReceiver {

    @StreamListener(MySink.INPUT)
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
    }
}

interface MySink {
    String INPUT = "input234242"; // The channel name

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel input();
}
```

Comment: Annotation-based programming model has been deprecated for almost 5 years and no longer supported. PLease migrate to functional based model - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_producing_and_consuming_messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to convert this to a functional style, this would do it.

```
public class RabbitMQReceiver {

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> receiveMessage() {
        return s -> {
           System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
        };
    }
}
```

and configuration:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition: receiveMessage 
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.receiveMessage-in-0.destination: <RabbitMQ Destination>
```

You only need to define `spring.cloud.function.definition` if you have more than one function beans that you want to activate.